# Remover linhas repetidas em todos os aspectos no Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query

Em uma coluna CADASTRO eu possuo  duas linhas repetidas em todos os aspectos:

```
NOME   ID    EMAIL           SEXO    
JOAO   1234  JOAO@GMAIL.COM  M
JOAO   1234  JOAO@GMAIL.COM  M
```

Como comparar essas duas linhas, conferir se todas as colunas estão idênticas e excluir uma delas a fim de resultar:

```
NOME   ID    EMAIL           SEXO    
JOAO   1234  JOAO@GMAIL.COM  M
```

Comment: Você não tem nenhum identificador único pra sua tabela?

Comment: Se para a pergunta do George (acima) for não, você pode alterar a estrutura da tabela? Não sei quanto ao Oracle, mas, no SQL Server não tem como remover apenas uma delas - precisa de um identificador único para cada registro.

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque não está claro se AP pretende fazer isto num Select ou existem dados duplicados que ele quer excluir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entendendo que você quer eliminar do banco de dados os registros duplicados mas, mantendo um (1) deles, sugiro utilizar o `rowid`.

O `ROWID` é uma pseudo-coluna que retorna o endereço de um registro, estruturalmente você não o verá, mas, está lá.
Ele identifica exclusivamente uma linha dentro de uma tabela.

No script abaixo temos:

- Uma sub-consulta buscando todos os menores `rowid` de cada agrupamento repetido;
- Um comando `delete` em todos os registros que não estão no agrupamento mínimo feito na sub-consulta;

**Script:**

```
delete from cadastro
where rowid not in
     (select min(rowid)
      from cadastro
group by nome, id, email, sexo);
```

Com isso, serão eliminados os duplicados deixando pelo menos um de cada.

*Obs: Você nunca deve armazenar um `rowid` em suas tabelas como um valor de chave (único).*

Answer (score 2):

Em sql server, o método abaixo funciona. Em oracle julgo que é semelhante:

```
select *
into #table
from(   select nome = 'JOAO', id=1234, email='JOAO@GMAIL.COM', sexo='m'
        union all
        select nome = 'JOAO', id=1234, email='JOAO@GMAIL.COM', sexo='m'
        union all
        select nome = 'manuel', id=1237, email='manuel@GMAIL.COM', sexo='m') t

   ;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT  *, 
                row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY nome,id,email,sexo ORDER BY nome,id,email,sexo) AS rn
        FROM #table
    )
    DELETE cte WHERE rn > 1

select * 
from #table

drop table #table
```

Answer (score 1):

Use um `distinct`.

```
Select Distinct * From Tabela;
```

[Veja funcionando no SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7bfa/1)

Comment: Mas ele precisa remover as linhas repetidas deixando apenas uma.

Comment: @Ismael Mas é isso que o distinct faz. Ou eu devo ter entendido errado (a pergunta e o seu comentário).

Comment: O que eu entendi que ele quer remover do banco de dados essas linhas "a mais" - ou seja, unificar esses cadastros.

Comment: Sua teoria faz sentido, mas é pouco provável. Aí ele teria dois registros com o mesmo **ID**? Claro que é possível, mas não acredito que seja o caso.

Comment: Tem cada sistema doido por aí que não custa duvidar. Vamos aguardar mais detalhes.

Comment: Sim, você tem razão. Também vou esperar por mais detalhes.

Comment: Pra que este link? @Motta

Comment: @jbueno , post removido

Comment: @Motta Eu realmente não entendi, rs. Mas tudo bem.